# Image is not being resized

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have form where the user chooses their profile picture and writes their bio. The form should take the uploaded image and resize it to 200x200. It uploads the picture, but the resizing does not take place. I tried following [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/02/how-to-crop-images-in-a-django-application.html): However, for some reason my image is still not able to resize when I upload it. Here's my code:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    avatar  = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput)
    bio     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, "placeholder": "Bio"}), max_length=200,
                          required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['avatar', 'bio', 'gender'']

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save()

    image = Image.open(profile.avatar)
    resized_image = image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    resized_image.save(profile.avatar.path)

    return profile

class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    user    = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio     = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    avatar  = models.ImageField(storage=OverwriteStorage(), upload_to=create_user_image_path)
    gender  = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True)
```

The image is being uploaded and everything is working fine, however, the image is not being resized.

Comment: Not sure what might be wrong, because the very same code worked for me(django 1.11)

Comment: @ruddra Also, my view is an `updateview`